# How do I know which database is configured SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm in a machine that has already SharePoint installed, so when I started the SharePoint Central Administration to config, this message appear to me: **"Can not connect to the database configuration."**

How do I know which database is configured SharePoint?

Comment: This belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, can someone move this question?

Answer (score 2):

Normally the Admin database is created using the naming convention SharePoint_AdminContent_{GUID}. However if there's more than one, you'll need to use SQL Management studo or other tool to look inside the DBs, look for a table called "DatabaseInformation" which will contain two items, look in the AlternateAccessMappingXML entry and look for the XML tage IncomingUrl, that should help you narrow it down.

Or just use the SQL profiler and watch for connections.

Comment: My MSSQLS/SHAREPOINT Service was disabled. I enabled it and now this error don't appear, but a username and password is requested.

Comment: Ok, so in the database you've now identifed on the SQL server, look under the security settings and there will be the list of accounts that have access there. In a minimal priviledge setup there is typically only 3 accounts, a service app account, a content account and a farm account. It's the FARM account that you'll need the password for. You'll need to try to identify which is which and hopefully whoever set it up used a sensible naming convention. I can't help with the pasword though - thats down to you :)

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint will install the Database on the same machine as the web server, but you can ask whoever installed SharePoint on the machine.

Anyhow, most likely it's not relevant and something else is the problem, follow the resolution methods [described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823287) and you'll probably have it fixed.

Comment: -1: the link points to a WSS 2.0 KB article. Plus, "but you can ask whoever installed SharePoint on the machine." is not an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Stefan I believe the "core" didn't change much in SharePoint 2010 so this is still relevant, as for "asking whoever installed" it's only part of the answer, would have posted only comment if that was all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The person who installed SharePoint in my machine is not working here anymore.

Comment: @Acaz did you try all methods described in the link?

Comment: @ShadowWizard My MSSQLS/SHAREPOINT Service was disabled. I enabled it and now this error don't appear, but a username and password is requested.